# Python - Selenium is not opening chrome to a static profile although having proper code for it

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to have selenium open chrome in a static browser profile however, nothing seems to be working as of now
here's the code

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Path to your chrome profile
options.add_argument(
    "user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\javin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3")



driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=topic"

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)
```

it's in python3 and the `version of selenium is 4.16.0`. Its still opening the browser in profile 1 or temp profile
and yes, its in **venv**

I wanted to have selenium open chrome in a static browser profile however, nothing seems to be working as of now
here's the code

Comment: did you test `--profile-directory=...`

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter issues with the specified user data directory in the provided argument, an alternative is to enhance specificity by incorporating the argument `'options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 4")'` in conjunction with the original code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Path to your chrome profile
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 4")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
```

This adjustment aims to refine the profile specification, potentially resolving any challenges associated with the initial user data directory setting.

Both the approaches below are correct:

1 approach:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 4")
```

2 approach:

```
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 4")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

Both approaches achieve the goal of using a specific Chrome profile, but the second approach provides a bit more flexibility by allowing you to set the main user data directory separately. It's also the method officially recommended by ChromeDriver for specifying profiles. The first approach is more direct but ties the profile directory directly to the user data directory.

**It is advisable to close the active Chrome browser and then execute the program.**